# typescript problem with multiple projects (references) and global declare files

Tags: typescript, declaration

I was always using [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) strategy to declare global to be accible all around my project without using import 
but lately I was trying to use multiple project config with references and it needs to build subprojects with declaration files but after I had set config to use references it doesn't recognise 
my global types

Answer (score 0):

now I found the answer
we need to add those global declare files to include pattern or files of all subprojects not only base one (which is used by referenced in other projects)